# How can I rotate a Pin live in Xamarin forms Google maps?

Tags: google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin Forms google maps application in which I need to rotate a pin based on certain live parameters from the PCL. How do I achieve this functionality?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: It's like hey you have this requirement, do that! 
Please write more about your problem. What is your live Params? What it looks like? What it does? Write your codes so that we can help on that.
"You have to use custom pin for that !"

Comment: How much more obvious can I get? Xamarin Forms Pin does not have a rotation property which you can simply change from the PCL and the rotation angle of the pin icon in the map changes dynamically. 

And regarding your "live param" concern. It can be anything. For simplicity sake the rotation angle is binded to a slider that the user can manually change through the UI.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use the following library for the map.
https://github.com/amay077/Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps
It supports the Pin rotation and many other features. Which is more easier than using the Xamarin Forms provided map.
I have just tested the Pin rotation. See the screenshot below.

[image]